# Generate Sequential POST requests via fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I am quite new to Fiddler and it looks like an awesome tool to me.

What i wanted to do is generate a sequence of POST requests.

Explaination:

> POST https://www.website.com/user/login HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.website.com
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 552
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Origin: https://www.website.com
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>   DNT: 1
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>   Referer: https://www.website.com/user/login
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>   Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mpdxdkrjujkzchwblg1ys2y3; ai_user=u0IpN|2018-09-25T16:12:07.607Z; ai_session=+Ip5T|1537899054881.5|1537899121420.5
>   __VIEWSTATE=something here PageContent%24txtRoll=14600&ctl00%24PageContent%24txtDOB=**01%2F01%2F2001**&ctl00%24PageContent%24btn_submit=LOGIN

i want to make a loop of request such that the DOB field takes value like

01%2F01%2F2001
then, 01%2F02%2F2001
then, 01%2F03%2F2001
and so on.. keeping everything else same.

And if the response from server is Code:302 then stop the loop or otherwise if the value reaches 31 then too stop the loop.

Thanks in advance.
Any suggestions are welcome.
P.S. :Sorry for the messy question, i don't know how could i say it in simple words.

Comment: I dont think fiddler supports such automation. I would create a simple console app or a LinqPad snippet for that. However it has an API testing tool that can be higly customized: https://www.google.hu/amp/s/www.telerik.com/amp/blogs/api-testing-with-telerik-fiddler

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script which will do that for you. Here's an article that might help you.

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddlerscript

Personally I'd write a script that does the task in python or any other language you know using any http library

Comment: See e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/httpfiddler/utilissuerequest%7Csort:date/httpfiddler/8r9Hop7LMXg/8W07E_950P4J